# List part of data in JSON file using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

anyone know how to list some/part of data from json file using php or javascript?

example if i using sql i must do code

```
select email from employees where name='Shyam'
```

but for json i don't have any clue how to do it.

```
{"employees":[  
    {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com", "job":"police"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "job":"athelic"},  
    {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com", "job":"king"}  
]}
```

by referring data above, i only want to select email where name=shyam by using php/javascript from json file.

Comment: Use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) on the `employees` array (or [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) - if you only ever want the first matching item)

Comment: Convert the JSON to JS using `JSON.parse` and then you can interact with it like a normal JS Object.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan can you show example of code my data?

Comment: @evolutionxbox how?

Comment: @botstudio, you actually miss one big point in your question. How do you get the data in your JS or PHP program?

Answer (score 1):

With Javascript you could do something like that :

```js
const data = {"employees": [  
  {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com", "job":"police"},  
  {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "job":"athelic"},  
  {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com", "job":"king"}  
]};

const result = data.employees.filter(employe => employe.name === "Shyam");
console.log(result);
```

And with PHP you can do that :

```
$data = json_decode('{"employees": [  
  {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com", "job":"police"},  
  {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "job":"athelic"},  
  {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com", "job":"king"}  
]}', true);

$result = array_filter($data['employees'], function ($employee) {
    return $employee['name'] === 'Shyam';
});
var_dump($result);
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can do something like this.

```
$json = '{"employees":[  
    {"name":"Shyam", "email":"shyamjaiswal@gmail.com", "job":"police"},  
    {"name":"Bob", "email":"bob32@gmail.com", "job":"athelic"},  
    {"name":"Jai", "email":"jai87@gmail.com", "job":"king"}  
]} ';

$jsonArray = json_decode($json, true);
$emails = [];

foreach ($jsonArray['employees'] as $item){
    if ($item['name'] == "Shyam") {
        $emails[] = $item['email'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Or Just use [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Answer (score 0):

Somethink like this (JS)?

```js
      const getEmail = (json, name) => {
        const row = json.employees.find(e => e.name === name);
        return row ? row.email : null;
      }
```